# Windows Service Reading from MSMQ through WCF...Throttling

Tags: wcf, windows-services, msmq, throttling

I have a windows service that reads my message queue through WCF. I want the service to process not more than 50 messages from queue. I set the throttling configuration to 50 , but it does not seem to do anything. It just process one message after the other.

Am i missing something?

My web.config :

`<serviceThrottling
        maxConcurrentCalls="1"
            maxConcurrentSessions="1"
            maxConcurrentInstances="50" />`

My Service File:

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]

Please let me know if there is anything to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should set maxConcurrentCalls and maxConcurrentSessions, can you try to remove them?